# Specific regex in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I created two functions .One checkUnit to get the unit from string and second whatU if input contains  m u n p T g k to convert the input value .But there is some mismatch .

My pattern examples:
"m(O|h|F|s|H|A|V)" -this is for the m before unit this part needs improve

\b0-9.*Ohm.*(?<![0-9])\b" - this is for Ohm this part is wrong

val pattern = Regex(whatToFind)
val result = pattern.containsMatchIn(whatToFind)

This is for all invalid characters in input [A-EI-LNP-SUW-Za-gi-jloq-tw-zvV/ '$&+,{}:;=_\[]|`~?@#"<>^*()%!-£€¥¢©®™¿÷¦¬×§¶°]

How to check if m is before Ohm and after number in string 100mOhm  in regex Kotlin in more effective way ?

Comment: please show some effort in what you have tried, so it is more clear what exactly is your problem here.

Comment: The edited question irritates me very much. Do the answers already help you? Maybe you can post your code? What is the variable `whatToFind`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). There are several predefined character classes like `\d+` for a digit. So you can use the following method:

```java
boolean matched = Pattern.matches("\\d+mOhm", "100mOhm");
```

Or if you want to have the pattern for a longer time you can use the following method:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+mOhm");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("100mOhm");
boolean matched = matcher.matches();
```

If you want to use only Kotlin, you can use the following code:

```kotlin
val regex = "\\d+mOhm".toRegex()
val matched = regex.matches("100mOhm")
```

I found also a nice [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-regular-expressions) with more information about Koltin Regex.

Answer (score 0):

This meets your requirement:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val s = scanner.nextLine()
    println("\\d+mOhm".toRegex().matches(s))
}
```

Perhaps you can modify it from here.